# Extracting information from INVITE request using Android SIP library

Tags: android, sip

Hi I am developing a SIP client on Android, using the ANDROID's SIP API.
I have started from sample given by ANDROID, And have modified it.

I am using Asterisk as SIP server , which uses an extension

exten => 111,SIPAddHeader(X-ABC:192.168.8.3)

same => n,Dial(SIP/user1,15,tT)

This generates an INVITE request,with an additional SIP header,

Is there any mechanism available through which I can extract this additional information contained in the INVITE request using Android's SIP API??

or anyway to extract the whole INVITE request??